# PyQt drag and drop event empty

Tags: python, drag-and-drop, pyqt, event-handling

I'm trying to figure out how dnd works with (py)qt. I tried several example applications and.. hm was wondering: how do I see what data is actually inside a drag/drop event? I tried printing the event, the **dict** of the event, the mimeData().text().. but no mater what i drag in there, there seems to be no data whatsoever. Eg if I drag over a '.desktop' file from /usr/share/applications, shouldn't there be info inside the drag event?

see this eg. application:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import signal
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore
from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt

class DragFromWidget(QtGui.QDockWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(DragFromWidget, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        self.layout().addWidget(QtGui.QLabel("Label!"))

class DragToWidget(QtGui.QDockWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(DragToWidget, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        #HOW?
        print event
        print event.__dict__
        print event.mimeData()
        print event.mimeData().__dict__
        print event.mimeData().text()
        event.accept()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        #HOW?
        print event
        print event.__dict__
        print event.mimeData()
        print event.mimeData().__dict__
        print event.mimeData().text()

class SandboxApp(QtGui.QApplication):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SandboxApp, self).__init__(*args)
        self.mainwindow = MainWindow()
        self.mainwindow.show()


class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        self.setDockOptions(QtGui.QMainWindow.AllowNestedDocks|QtGui.QMainWindow.AnimatedDocks)
        self.addDockWidget(Qt.LeftDockWidgetArea, DragFromWidget())
        self.addDockWidget(Qt.RightDockWidgetArea, DragToWidget())


def main():
    app = SandboxApp(sys.argv)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: If you're dragging a file, then no, there won't be any data other than the file-path. Or to put it another way: the data *is* the file-path. If you want the contents of the file, just read it.

Comment: Thnx I found it ! I came across an example that worked. For anyone interested, look at event.mimeData().urls(). Still would be curious how to view all data in this 'event'. Would be nice if this would be possible. Using .__dict__ didnt work...

Comment: What do you mean by "all data"? What specific information are you looking for? The docs for [QMimeData](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qmimedata.html), [QDropEvent](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qdropevent.html) and [QDragEnterEvent](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qdragenterevent.html) show you what's available.